# upload file to google bucket from remote url in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

We have found various solutions around upload the file to google cloud bucket from local system. However I am wondering if is there a way we can upload file to bucket using the public URL or link.

https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-storage/latest/index.html

I want to upload a file from remote url to GCS bucket via ruby code. Any suggestion here would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sits between the remote URL and the Google Cloud Storage (GCS) Bucket.

You've 2 alternatives:

1. (As you describe) Download the file behind the remote URL to a file system accessible to your code and then upload it to GCS;
2. [Stream](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming) the file from the remote location into memory (you'll need to write this) and then (using GCS client library) stream the file into a GCS object.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged question with `ruby-on-rails-3`

Old rails versions use uploaders like carrierwave

It's possible to use it to [upload files to GCS](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-google-cloud-storage)

You can upload not only local files using this gem but also [from remote URL](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#uploading-files-from-a-remote-location), just use special attribute